# Bash script for start the tomcat when it stops or is not running

Tags: bash, tomcat

How to restart the tomcat server by help of bash script when it gets down automatically?

Is given script Ok for tomcat restart?

```
#!/bin/sh

ps -ef | grep tomcat | grep -v grep > /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    tomcatup > /dev/null
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ps` is not suitable for checking whether a server is up. It would fail you if you have any "tomcat" on your process list, e.g. when reading tomcat-manual.pdf or editing tomcat.config.

Better start tomcat in non-deamon mode in an endless loop or utilize a services system like **systemd**.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Do you have any script for tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Small Bash script for start the tomcat.

## !/bin/bash

ps -ef|grep tomcat > /root/tt
num=`wc -l tt |awk '{print$1}'`
if [ "$num" == 2 ];
then
tomcatup or /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh

### fi